# Grid works great, but shows no data

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, grid

So I have the grid.Panel here :

```
Ext.require([
    'Ext.direct.*',
    'Ext.data.*',
    'Ext.grid.*'
]);
Ext.define('PersonalInfo', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [ 'name', 'email']
});

Ext.onReady(function() {
    // create the Grid
    Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        store: {
            model: 'PersonalInfo',
            autoLoad: true,
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                 url : 'app/data/users.json',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'users'
                }
            }
        },
        columns: [{
            dataIndex: 'name',
            width: 50,
            text: 'ID'
        }],
        height: 450,
        width: 700,
        title: 'Velociraptor Owners',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
});
```

And the users.json file here, who's extension is app/data/users.json:

```
{
    "users": [
        { "name": "Name 1" , "email": "email@site.com" },
        { "name": "Name 2" , "email": "email@site.com" },
        { "name": "Name 3" , "email": "email@site.com" },
        { "name": "Name 4" , "email": "email@site.com" },
        { "name": "Name 5" , "email": "email@site.com" }
    ]
}
```

The grid displays on my browser (Firefox. IE9 doesn't display anything) but is not displaying the "name" field like I told it to. Any ideas?

Comment: This works fine for me on both Chrome 28 and IE9 using 4.2.1. Which version are you using? Are you sure it's not an AJAX problem? i.e you're certain data is being returned?

Comment: It seems perfect check the JSON data you are getting through AJAX request.

Comment: +1 for the great title.